# How to insert `>` and `(` into MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I do not know where is the problem that I can not insert `>` and `(` into my MySQL database.

I add a `addslashes($str)` but this still can leave the quote mark unescaped.

Is there any string functions that can solve my problem?

Comment: How does your code look like?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Don't use `addslashes()`](http://www.sadtrombone.com/), use...

## [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

### Use it every time your interpolate outside strings into a query!

...or better still, use binded parameters with something like PDO.

<sup>By the way, there is no reason why `>` and `)` wouldn't be inserted into your database that I can think of. They have no meaning inside of a string, unlike `\`.</sup>

Comment: Makes me wish I wasn't rep capped :)